How to properly fix class duplicate ? Unity Android Build
I've been struggling 2 days on this build error, I didn't succeed by myself so im looking for your help.
I have these duplicated classes, and I don't know where they are stored nor which one should I remove.
For example "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3" has a duplicate with "jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime" but I cant find any of them. I just have "androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1" in Plugins/Android and the ktx version, but removing the ktx doesn't change anything.
I have :
■ deleted library
■ Reimported GooglePlay SDK
■ Deleted resolved libraries
■Force resolved
I tried custom gradle lines from internet forums but none worked.
Context :
■Unity 2022.3.46f1
■Building apk for android : targeting API 34
■GooglePlay SDK
■Playfab SDK
■Unity IAP
■Unity Advertisement Legacy
Thanks for your time
Here's the error log
Note: C:\Users\lemec\Documents\GitHub\Chromagone\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.RemoteActionCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.Cancellable found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$1 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2$1 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2$2 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$3 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$4 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$5 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$NonConfigurationInstances found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ImmLeaksCleaner found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher$LifecycleOnBackPressedCancellable found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher$OnBackPressedCancellable found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAware found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.contextaware.OnContextAvailableListener found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult$1 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCaller found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$3 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$CallbackAndContract found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$LifecycleContainer found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistryOwner found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.IntentSenderRequest found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.IntentSenderRequest$Builder found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract$SynchronousResult found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$CreateDocument found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$GetContent found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$GetMultipleContents found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$OpenDocument found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$OpenDocumentTree found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$OpenMultipleDocuments found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$PickContact found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$RequestMultiplePermissions found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$RequestPermission found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$StartActivityForResult found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$StartIntentSenderForResult found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$TakePicture found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$TakePicturePreview found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$TakeVideo found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimatorRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyThread found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ArrayRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AttrRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BinderThread found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BoolRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.CallSuper found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotati<message truncated>


There is no build.gradle, which means you've provided no actual context; tagging it as build.gradle does not count. Don't mix android.support with androidx and disable the Jetifier. androidx.core , androidx.activity  and androidx.annotation are definitely added twice.

I just tried to uncheck jetifier, but everytime i resolve Unity enable it back. And building without resolving still lead to duplicate class
I also tried to remove every .aar with "support" in the name but nothing seem to change
I don't know how gradle works, i'm clueless.
I used all my knowledge.
I don't know if I did properly what you proposed
